# PGFplots-warning: Sorry, the colorbar is uninitialised - your axis has no color data

Tags: pgfplots

When trying to place a colorbar for a plot with only graphics, I get this warning:

> Sorry, the colorbar is uninitialized - your axis has no color data.
>   Consider using 'point meta=f(x)' or something like that. I am using a
>   color range of [0,1] for the colorbar.

So, how can I properly initialize the colorbar?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    colorbar, colorbar style ={
        point meta min =100,
        point meta max =200
    },
    ]
    \addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=50,ymin=0,ymax=10] {example-image};
    \end{axis}
    %
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not know any clean way to switch off the warning but of course you can cheat, i.e. make pgfplots happy by adding `\addplot [domain=0:50,point meta=100+2*x,draw=none] {0.1*x};` where `draw=none` ensures that your figure does not get spoiled.

Comment: @marmot Not clean but works `:)` I am a bit lazy to look for the meaning of `point meta=100+2*x` but I found that `point meta = 0` is enough for completing the task.

Comment: Yes, it is just a warning anyway. The reason for this formula is to make sure `meta` runs from 100 to 200, but as you say it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is either because the point meta values are checked before the `colorbar style` keys or because the `axis` itself does not get access to the `colorbar style` keys. Thus, making the warning disappear you could either state the point meta keys directly to the `axis` options or state them in the `\addplot` options.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        colorbar,
        % either state the point meta keys in the `axis' options ...
        point meta min=100,
        point meta max=200,
    ]
        \addplot [
%            % ... or in the `\addplot' options to make the warning disappear
%            point meta min=100,
%            point meta max=200,
        ] graphics [xmin=0,xmax=50,ymin=0,ymax=10] {example-image};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]